# The "CarouselView" control cannot work right?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to use "CarouselView"(not the CarouselView.FormsPlugin) in my project But it always cause an error :"The Specified Cast is not Valid" even I use the official sample in the blog.

I think there is a possibility that it is not supported in the version 3.6 since it's version is 4.0

Here is my code

```
<CarouselView x:Name="CV" ItemsSource="Menus" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="10">
                <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </CarouselView>
```

The ItemsSource is An ObservableCollection But it always cause an error.

My xamarin.forms version is :3.6.293080

Comment: I am facing the same issue since yesterday will let you know if i find a solution

Comment: Thank you @G.hakim I have tried many times and cannot find a solution I think we have to update the xamarin version to 4.00

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Hi @G.hakim this is all the code and the source of the CarouselView is only a ObservableCollection of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My issue got solved when I removed the `ViewCell` and kept `ContentView` as the first child of the `DataTemplate`

```
<CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <ContentView>
                   <Button Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="14"/>
                  </ContentView>
              </DataTemplate>
</CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

I'm not sure what the Knitty gritty is with this issue but this solved mine.

Comment: you are so awesome

Comment: when I tried then Mark it . If there is any problem I will tell you. Thank you.

Comment: Sure let me know for the same

Comment: It works for me.Thank you.G.hakim you have helpped me many times

Comment: @daotian It's my pleasure, I do not remember many times but i am glad to help

Comment: Indeed I do feel free to check my profile/blogs and get back to me if you do not understand something

Comment: It cause an error of specified cast is not valid today.what it is wrong?

Comment: Did you remove the ContentView?

Comment: no matter remove or not it cause an error on vs for mac.and works well in windows

Comment: Are you sure the mac machine has the proper NuGet's?

Comment: what you mean the proper Nuget's?

Comment: Are the package's available?

Comment: I think so and I update all the package to the latest.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look into this!

Comment: what shoul I do ?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Open the MAC and Compare the Version of Carousel in both and once you do that if there are any discrepancies correct them

Comment: It's over a year later and I ran into the same issue. Your solution works, thank you.